# Programmatically get application usage from Screen Time in iOS 12

Tags: ios, iphone-x, xcode10, ios12

I am working on one project and I want to get other application usage time. apple has launched iOS 12 and provides the new feature `Screen Time`. I want to know is there any way or API provided by Apple to get data from it.

Comment: After WWDC22, I guess now you can do this! https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, on iOS each app runs in its own sandbox and cannot see data from other apps, even apps from the same publisher. An app can access special shared data, like photos from the album or contact data, but it is not possible for an app to directly access files written by other apps.

ScreenTime application is on another sandbox than your app. Unless apple provide API we can't access the same.

---

### Update

Since apple have added screen time app into ios12 simulator. There could be a chance they provide the API's soon.

Comment: Has there been any update regarding Apple Screen Time API

Comment: @juske no updates from apple on Apple Screen Time APIs

Comment: 3 years later, is it still the same case?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 15 Apple has added an API, see here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/FamilyControls

> **FamilyControls**
>
> Authorize your app to provide parental controls on a
> child’s device. To authorize your parental controls app, use a shared
> AuthorizationCenter instance. You can authorize parental controls only
> on a device that is part of a Family Sharing group and signed into a
> child’s iCloud account.

You must add the Family Controls capability to your app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to provide functionality to parental control apps only. In other words, it cannot be used by other time-tracking or productivity apps at the moment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).