# Get phone usage stats on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios15

I am building a mobile app for digital detox which requires tracking app usage by the user.

On android we have the [Usage Stats Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) that provides events as well as aggregated stats and works well.

Apple announced [ScreenTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screentime) and [DeviceActivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceActivity) recently which are synonymous is nature to UsageStatsManager but there is no documentation for the APIs of either.

A related question ([Programmatically get application usage from Screen Time in iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472729/programmatically-get-application-usage-from-screen-time-in-ios-12/52472920#52472920)) suggests [FamilyControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/FamilyControls) but it does not work without enrolling the device as a child device.

Any direction with the two APIs or method for screen time tracking on iOS will be much appreciated.

Comment: In this announcment you can find some information about this problem: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/
But I'm still unsure how the "privacy preserving" way actually works. I would like to do some calculations on the data and therefore the raw data is necessary. I'm not sure if this is possible at the moment.

Comment: You can request authorisation with `AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: FamilyControlsMember.individual)`. and dont forget to add capabilities in the main target.